# Pooling asymmetric confidence intervals for proportions?

Tags: bayesian, confidence-interval, estimation, binomial-distribution, multilevel-analysis

I have several measurements of proportions (values in [0, 1]) $\theta_1,...,\theta_n$, each with an (asymmetric) 95% confidence interval. The $\theta$'s are repeated measurements of the same variable in the world and so I'd like to pool them together to get an estimate of $\hat{\theta}$ with its own confidence intervals (which can be asymmetric.) The important thing is that I'd like the estimate to downweight measurements in proportion to the width of their confidence interval. If I have $\theta_{1} = 0.6$ with CIs $(0.5,0.7)$ and $\theta_{2} = 0.8$ with CIs $(0.3,0.9)$ then I'd like the estimate $\hat{\theta}$ to weight $\theta_{1}$ more highly and thus give an estimate closer to 0.6 than to 0.8 (but also respect the asymmetry of $\theta_{2}$'s confidence intervals.)

What's a general way to do this?

One simple minded way to get $\hat{\theta}$ is to use the size of each CI in a weighted sum:

$s_1 = 0.7 - 0.5, s_2 = 0.9 - 0.3$

$\hat{\theta} = \frac{\theta_{1}(1/s_{1}) + \theta_{2}(1/s_{2})}{(1/s_{1}) + (1/s_{2})}$

But that doesn't yield a CI for $\hat{\theta}$ and does not use the asymmetry of the CIs of $\theta_{1},\theta_{2}$, it only uses their size. How can this be done correctly?  Does one have to transform the proportions to a variable that can be modeled by a more well-behaved distribution like a Gaussian?

Final variant of this question: each proportion $\theta_i$ was obtained by monte carlo sampling. Each $\theta_i$ is just the mean value of that distribution (which was a posterior distribution for $\theta_{i}$) and the 95% intervals are derived from the samples used to estimate the distribution. That means I have more information about each $\theta_i$ than just the posterior mean and CIs; I actually have an entire distribution of values for it and so are there general methods to use these here as well?   thanks.

p.s. I'm happy with the most minimal assumptions about how the $\theta$'s are related to each other. Theoretically, they are all measurements of the same variable but each measurement has distinct amounts of noise. I have no strong priors on the noise process.